# jQuery ajax image upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

as the title describes i would like to create an image upload with ajax with jQuery. As far as I know right now, there is no image ajax uploading. Workarounds are iframes and flash. Since i don't like flash, i'm fine with the iframe hack, i hope. Like they do it here: http://tinyw.in/UNnp

I have an  element. I want to make it possible, to double click on the element, then a file browser appears, you choose your image, it gets uploaded and the image's src you just clicked get's changed to the new uploaded image's path. Doesn't really sound that hard.

Actually, that's what the link i posted above does. I don't know what it does in detail, how it handels everything, since there is no documentation.

So, can me anyone explain what that plugin does in the backend, so i understand it. I don't know what i should do with the php.php file, what i should pass as an action of the form.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ this plugin is very nice. Just create a form, init the plugin with it and you are done. Just handle the uploaded files within PHP's $_FILES[]

Answer (score 0):

the plugin you mentioned uses [ajax-upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). This project has some server side scripts on their github repository. Have a look [here](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/tree/master/server)

Comment: Yes, i know. I tried to use them but failed. It's sad that he doesn't have a working demo. I'm still learning, so sometimes i don't get it myself.